# Combining multiple columns and insert information in middle

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, text-formatting, paste

I have to 3 files with all containing columns of information

**id.file**

```
1
2
3
```

**name.file**

```
Josh
Kate
Chris
```

**lastname.file**

```
Smith
Jones
Black
```

And I would like to combine them in a way, so I can get something like this:

```
The ID of the Josh Smith is 1
The ID of the Kate Jones is 2
The ID of the Chris Black is 3
```

So far I have tried to combine them using paste `paste -d ',' id.file name.file lastname.file` which works well but I want to add words in the beginning and between values as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
paste name.file lastname.file id.file | awk -F '\t' '{printf "The ID of the %s %s is %d\n", $1,$2,$3}'
```

Using `awk` to get the formatting needed.

Comment: Your example works really well, can I ask what do multiple %s and %d do?

Comment: The %s %s and %d gets replaced with first name($1), last name($2) and id($3)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution (assuming there is always single column in each files) would be:

```
paste name.file lastname.file id.file |xargs printf 'the id of the %s %s is %d\n'
```

Or with `awk` only and with no column limitation:

```
awk '{ getline name<"name.file"; getline lastname<"lastname.file"}
     { print "the Id of the", name, lastname, "is", $0 }' OFS=' ' id.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a program from the Icon library (a symbol-manipulation language in the sense of SNOBOL):

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input data files" data?
head data?

pl " Expected output:"
head -v $E

# Insert strings like:
# The ID of the Josh Smith is 1
pl " Results:"
icon-paste "-The ID of the " data2 "- " data3 "- is " data1 |
tee f1

pl " Verify results if possible:"
C=$HOME/bin/pass-fail
[ -f $C ] && $C f1 "$E" || ( pe; pe " Results cannot be verified." ) >&2
```

producing:

```
-----
 Input data files data1 data2 data3
==> data1 <==
1
2
3

==> data2 <==
Josh
Kate
Chris

==> data3 <==
Smith
Jones
Black

-----
 Expected output:
==> expected-output <==
The ID of the Josh Smith is 1
The ID of the Kate Jones is 2
The ID of the Chris Black is 3

-----
 Results:
The ID of the Josh Smith is 1
The ID of the Kate Jones is 2
The ID of the Chris Black is 3

-----
 Verify results if possible:

-----
 Comparison of 3 created lines with 3 lines of desired results:
 Succeeded -- files (computed) f1 and (standard) expected-output have same content.
```

This was on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-7-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.11 (jessie)
```

Some details on icon-paste (lam.icn):

```
icon-paste      paste, join, laminate lines from files. (man)
Path    : ~/executable/icon-paste
Version : - ( local: ~/executable/icon-paste, 2012-02-11 )
Length  : 24 lines
Type    : POSIX shell script executable (binary data)
Shebang : #!/bin/sh
Home    : https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/library/src/progs/lam.icn (doc)
```

Information on Icon can be found at:

```
https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl